# Current user in pre_delete signal in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Is it possible to get a signed in django user (that calls model's delete method) in a callback connected to pre_delete signal?

Comment: you'll probably have to go with the treadlocal approach, but there might be a better approach to your problem depending on what you are trying to achieve, in other words, you need to give more information about your problem's context

Comment: There is an on-delete trigger in the backend db that store info in some table about deleted records in other tables. I need information who (which django user) initiated the delete action, so I'm trying to use an approach that will update the to-be-deleted record with django-user id, and that way user will be available for the trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pre_delete` signal doesn't pass the request instance, but you can add a decorator, that adds it, and to use that decorator on a view, which deletes the specified Model.

Assuming that this is the callback function:

```
def pre_delete_cb(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    pass
```

which is being added in the decorator:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

def pre_delete_dec(cb, sender):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            cb.request = request  # here we add the request to the callback function
            pre_delete.connect(cb, sender=sender)  # and connecting the real pre_delete to the callback
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

And use the decorator on the view in the way you call it - instead of `pre_delete.connect(pre_delete_cb, MyModel)`, use:

```
@pre_delete_dec(pre_delete_cb, MyModel)
def myview(request):
```

and then in the callback you'll have access to the request as:

```
def pre_delete_cb(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    current_user = pre_delete_cb.request.user
```

You can add this on global level, not just per view - using a Middleware:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

def pre_delete_cb(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    current_user = pre_delete_cb.request.user

class PreDeleteMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        pre_delete_cb.request = request
        from myapp.models import MyModel
        pre_delete.connect(pre_delete_cb, sender=MyModel)
```

Comment: Is it possible to create more general solution, for several Models? In your solution, if I understand it correctly, each view would have to be decorated for each model separately.

Comment: Sure, using the Middleware. Just delete the last 2 lines of PreDeleteMiddleware  and add them somewhere in your code, for whatever model you like. Just use the pre_delete_cb callback method in `pre_delete.connect(pre_delete_cb, sender=some_model)`. The middleware have nothing to do with the actual Model indeed. It just needs to set the request property to the callback function. But you can use the decorator too - move the pre_delete.connect out of it. It just needs the request objects and the callback.