# Django signals pre_delete accessing request.user

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to access request.user within pre_delete signal?  I found an answer but that was 10 years ago and doesn't work with the current version of Django.

Comment: plz put code for a batter answer

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala
Here is the solution from 10 years ago and doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499953/current-user-in-pre-delete-signal-in-django